# INNER JOIN table does not show data in JAVA project, query works fine

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm sorry first cause my code in not in English.

The table in java netbeans does not show the data, but in MySQL it creates a table for me exactly as I want. Query ran fine but the result set was empty

Table trening_1:
[image: Table trening_1]

Table igrac:
[image: Table igrac]

Table in Java project to retrieve data, retrieve empty:
[image: Table in Java project to retrieve data, retrieve empty]

query works fine:
[image: query works fine]

```
 public void TreningSijecanj(JTable table)
        
{
    PreparedStatement prepareds;
    ResultSet result;
    
    String getQuery1 ="SELECT  `ime`, `prezime`,`training_id`, `2.1`, `5.1`, `8.1`, `15.1`, `20.1`, `22.1`, `25.1`, `30.1` FROM `igrac` INNER JOIN  `trening_1` ON `igrac`.`id`= `trening_1`.`training_id`";
    
   
    
   
    try {
       
        prepareds = conn1.createConnection().prepareStatement(getQuery1);
        
         DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
         result = prepareds.executeQuery();
         Object[] row;
         
    while(result.next())
    {
        row=new Object[11];
        row[0]=result.getString(1);
        row[1]=result.getString(2);
        row[2]=result.getInt(3);
        row[3]=result.getString(4);
        row[4]=result.getString(5);
        row[5]=result.getString(6);
        row[6]=result.getString(7);
        row[7]=result.getString(8);
        row[8]=result.getString(9);
        row[9]=result.getString(10);
        row[10]=result.getString(11);
    tableModel.addRow(row);
    }
        
        
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TreningClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
}
```

CODE to show table
public class TreningForma extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
TreningClass trening = new TreningClass();

/**
 * Creates new form TreningForma
 */
public TreningForma() {
    initComponents();
    
    trening.TreningSijecanj(jTableTrening);

}
```

Comment: Please don't tag spam. This question does not appear related to C and javascript.

Comment: An interesting use of back ticks. I don't supposed you tried single-quotes instead ?

Comment: Drop all those backtics. None of them are needed, and they are wrong around things that are not referring to database objects (columns, tables), like around a number.

Comment: @trincot 2.1, 5.1, 8.1, etc are column names and they need the backticks.

Comment: You are joining `ON igrac.id= trening_1.training_id` but there are no common values between them so you get nothing in the results.

Comment: Indeed, really bad choice of column names there.

Comment: Thank you forpas :) now i saw that, I added some more values in training_id table , its works fine now